# Retrofit 2 Android : onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, retrofit

This is the JSON file I used from Cricapi but I couldn't get the data using Retrofit2 library. Every time I try to parse the data it showed this below error. I think there is error in my code. May be I should change the way to parse the data? Where should I change?

onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

But i use these below pojo class. but where is wrong. i don't understand.

[json format](http://ideone.com/iLvBNP)

This is the json i want to parse

```
{
"cache": true,
"data": [{
    "unique_id": "1051827",
    "description": "Auckland v Wellington",
    "title": "Auckland v Wellington"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1051825",
    "description": "Northern Districts v Canterbury",
    "title": "Northern Districts v Canterbury"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1051829",
    "description": "Otago v Central Districts",
    "title": "Otago v Central Districts"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053563",
    "description": "Baroda 93/10 &amp;  200/10 * v Tamil Nadu 337/10 ",
    "title": "Baroda 93/10 &amp;  200/10 * v Tamil Nadu 337/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053561",
    "description": "Mumbai 345/10  v Railways 160/10 &amp;  135/4 *",
    "title": "Mumbai 345/10  v Railways 160/10 &amp;  135/4 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053565",
    "description": "Punjab 61/2 &amp;  319/10 * v Uttar Pradesh 95/10 &amp;  335/10 ",
    "title": "Punjab 61/2 &amp;  319/10 * v Uttar Pradesh 95/10 &amp;  335/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053569",
    "description": "Assam 171/10  v Saurashtra 153/10 &amp;  0/1 *",
    "title": "Assam 171/10  v Saurashtra 153/10 &amp;  0/1 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053573",
    "description": "Delhi 334/10 &amp;  165/1 * v Jharkhand 493/10 ",
    "title": "Delhi 334/10 &amp;  165/1 * v Jharkhand 493/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053575",
    "description": "Karnataka 267/10 &amp;  209/10  v Vidarbha 111/10 &amp;  176/10 *",
    "title": "Karnataka 267/10 &amp;  209/10  v Vidarbha 111/10 &amp;  176/10 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053571",
    "description": "Rajasthan 323/10  v Odisha 172/10 &amp;  244/2 *",
    "title": "Rajasthan 323/10  v Odisha 172/10 &amp;  244/2 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053579",
    "description": "Andhra 177/1 * v Services 446/10 ",
    "title": "Andhra 177/1 * v Services 446/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053583",
    "description": "Chhattisgarh 95/2 &amp;  198/10 * v Goa 270/10 ",
    "title": "Chhattisgarh 95/2 &amp;  198/10 * v Goa 270/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053581",
    "description": "Himachal Pradesh 370/10  v Jammu &amp; Kashmir 337/4 &amp;  162/10 *",
    "title": "Himachal Pradesh 370/10  v Jammu &amp; Kashmir 337/4 &amp;  162/10 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1053585",
    "description": "Kerala 404/9  v Haryana 303/10 &amp;  6 *",
    "title": "Kerala 404/9  v Haryana 303/10 &amp;  6 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047915",
    "description": "Lahore Blues v Karachi Blues",
    "title": "Lahore Blues v Karachi Blues"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047919",
    "description": "United Bank Limited v Habib Bank Limited",
    "title": "United Bank Limited v Habib Bank Limited"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047921",
    "description": "Water and Power Development Authority v Sui Southern Gas Corporation",
    "title": "Water and Power Development Authority v Sui Southern Gas Corporation"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047923",
    "description": "Karachi Whites v Federally Administered Tribal Areas",
    "title": "Karachi Whites v Federally Administered Tribal Areas"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047929",
    "description": "Khan Research Laboratories v Pakistan International Airlines",
    "title": "Khan Research Laboratories v Pakistan International Airlines"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047925",
    "description": "Lahore Whites v Rawalpindi",
    "title": "Lahore Whites v Rawalpindi"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047927",
    "description": "Sui Northern Gas Pipelines Limited v National Bank of Pakistan",
    "title": "Sui Northern Gas Pipelines Limited v National Bank of Pakistan"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1059375",
    "description": "Speen Ghar Region 324/10  v Mis Ainak Region 100/3 &amp;  519/10 *",
    "title": "Speen Ghar Region 324/10  v Mis Ainak Region 100/3 &amp;  519/10 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1059376",
    "description": "Band-e-Amir Region 261/10 &amp;  255/10  v Boost Region 85/2 &amp;  334/10 *",
    "title": "Band-e-Amir Region 261/10 &amp;  255/10  v Boost Region 85/2 &amp;  334/10 *"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1047917",
    "description": "Islamabad v Peshawar",
    "title": "Islamabad v Peshawar"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1059377",
    "description": "Amo Region 113/8 &amp;  172/10 * v Kabul Green 264/10 ",
    "title": "Amo Region 113/8 &amp;  172/10 * v Kabul Green 264/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1059703",
    "description": "Zimbabwe 126/2 * v Sri Lanka 504/10 ",
    "title": "Zimbabwe 126/2 * v Sri Lanka 504/10 "
}, {
    "unique_id": "1026851",
    "description": "Hong Kong v Papua New Guinea",
    "title": "Hong Kong v Papua New Guinea"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1063054",
    "description": "Comilla Victorians v Chittagong Vikings",
    "title": "Comilla Victorians v Chittagong Vikings"
}, {
    "unique_id": "1063053",
    "description": "Barisal Bulls v Dhaka Dynamites",
    "title": "Barisal Bulls v Dhaka Dynamites"
}],
"provider": {
    "pubDate": "2016-11-07T18:13:30.006Z",
    "source": "Various",
    "url": "http://cricapi.com/"
}
```

i also make pojo class using web tool

1) First POJO class

```
@SerializedName("cache")
private Boolean cache;
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<Datum>();
@SerializedName("provider")
private Provider provider;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, 
Object>();

/**
 * @return The cache
 */
public Boolean getCache() {
    return cache;
}

/**
 * @param cache The cache
 */
public void setCache(Boolean cache) {
    this.cache = cache;
}

/**
 * @return The data
 */
public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

/**
 * @param data The data
 */
public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 * @return The provider
 */
public Provider getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

/**
 * @param provider The provider
 */
public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

2)Second POJO class

```
@SerializedName("unique_id")
private String uniqueId;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("title")
private String title;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, 
Object>();

/**
 * @return The uniqueId
 */
public String getUniqueId() {
    return uniqueId;
}

/**
 * @param uniqueId The unique_id
 */
public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
    this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
}

/**
 * @return The description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * @param description The description
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

/**
 * @return The title
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

/**
 * @param title The title
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

3) Third POJO class

```
@SerializedName("pubDate")
private String pubDate;
@SerializedName("source")
private String source;
@SerializedName("url")
private String url;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * @return The pubDate
 */
public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

/**
 * @param pubDate The pubDate
 */
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

/**
 * @return The source
 */
public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

/**
 * @param source The source
 */
public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

/**
 * @return The url
 */
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

/**
 * @param url The url
 */
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

My retrofit's API service

```
@GET("api/cricket/")
Call<List<AllMatchItemObject>> getAllMatchList();
```

Retrofit call

```
    showpDialog();
    try {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://cricapi.com/").
                        addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<List<AllMatchItemObject>> call = service.getAllMatchList();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AllMatchItemObject>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AllMatchItemObject>> call, Response<List<AllMatchItemObject>> response) {
                List<AllMatchItemObject> AllMatchItemObjectData = response.body();

                Log.d("onResponse", response.toString());
                hidepDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AllMatchItemObject>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        hidepDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 options. First one is change your json response such that current json response add inside Array( [ ]).  Second change retrofit annotation. Change Call<AllMatchItemObject> getAllMatchList()

Comment: 1) But json starts with json object 2) what is wrong with call. can you please explain :

Comment: You are using Call<List< all >> method, that means retrofit looking for array response from server, but your array starts with object that's why error occured. If u use only Call< all > then retrofit looking for objects.

Comment: @Divyesh now i face this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field shaoniiuc.com.cricketz.pojo.AllMatchItemObject.provider has type java.security.Provider, got com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap

Comment: I think you used Provider Object for your provider field as in your json response. That's why it giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://cricapi.com/").
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<AllMatchItemObject> call = service.getAllMatch();



    call.enqueue(new Callback<AllMatchItemObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AllMatchItemObject> call, Response<AllMatchItemObject> response) {
            AllMatchItemObject allMatchItemObjectData = response.body();

            Log.d("onResponse", response.toString());
            hidepDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AllMatchItemObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
    e.printStackTrace();
    hidepDialog();
}
```

Changing API service class

```
@GET("api/cricket/")

Call<AllMatchItemObject> getAllMatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in  type `Call<List<AllMatchItemObject>> call = service.getAllMatchList();`
In your json, Json start with object by you are getting as Array of

Use it `Call<AllMatchItemObject> call = service.getAllMatch();`

Answer (score -1):

change your API service to,

```
@GET("api/cricket/")
Call<AllMatchItemObject> getAllMatch();
```

and your retrofit call to,

```
showpDialog();
    try {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://cricapi.com/").
                        addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<AllMatchItemObject> call = service.getAllMatch();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<AllMatchItemObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllMatchItemObject> call, Response<AllMatchItemObject> response) {
                AllMatchItemObject allMatchItemObjectData = response.body();

                Log.d("onResponse", response.toString());
                hidepDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllMatchItemObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        hidepDialog();
    }
}
```

try this.